# How do I distribute a number into 4 even numbers?

Tags: javascript

So, I have got 4 random numbers:

Let's say that I want to evenly distribute all of them so they are all equal. If I have any remainders, then the remainder will be added onto the first number.

```
var a = number1 + number2 + number3 + number4;
var b = math.floor(number1) + math.floor(number2) + math.floor(number3) + math.floor(number4) + 0;
var c = math.floor(number1) + math.floor(number2) + math.floor(number3) + math.floor(number4) + 1;
var d = math.floor(number1) + math.floor(number2) + math.floor(number3) + math.floor(number4) + 2;
var e = math.floor(number1) + math.floor(number2) + math.floor(number3) + math.floor(number4) + 3;


if (a = b){
 remainder0()
}
if (a = c){
 remainder1()
}
if (a = d){
 remainder2()
}
if (a = e){
 remainder3()
}

function remainder0(){
number1 = (a / 4);
number2 = a / 4; 
number3 = a / 4;
number4 = a / 4;
}

function remainder1(){
number1 = (a / 4) + 1;
number2 = a / 4; 
number3 = a / 4;
number4 = a / 4;
}

function remainder2(){
number1 = (a / 4) + 2;
number2 = a / 4; 
number3 = a / 4;
number4 = a / 4;
}

function remainder3(){
number1 = (a / 4) + 3;
number2 = a / 4; 
number3 = a / 4;
number4 = a / 4;
}
```

The if statements don't appear to be working and if the remainder0() function works the 4 numbers seem to be out of place and make sense.

Comment: Can you please provide an input and the expected output?

Comment: I do not have my code at the moment. But I'll try to describe it.

Comment: Just provide an example, like "having 10, 15, 5, 10 I'm expecting 10, 10, 10, 10".

Comment: Let's say that I have; 13 30 30 30. If  I try to evenly distribute it with a click of a button it should be 28, 25, 25 25 because 100 is divisible by 4 and there is a remainder of 3 that gets added onto the first number.

Comment: `if (a = b)`  - you are doing an *assignment* here

Comment: `a=b` assign value `b` to `a`, `a==b` comparison, `a===b` typesafe comparison *(that's what you want)*

Answer (score 3):

You can get the sum of all the numbers, then work out what that sum is divided by the number of numbers you have. Then, you can work out the remainder, and add it to the first number:

```js
const evenlyDistribute = numbers => {
  const sum = numbers
    .reduce((p, c) => p + c, 0);
  
  const evenly = Math.floor(sum / numbers.length);
  const remainder = sum % numbers.length;
  
  const asList = Array.from(new Array(numbers.length).keys())
    .fill(evenly);
    
  return asList.map((x, i) => i === 0 ? x + remainder : x);
}

const x = evenlyDistribute([13, 30, 30, 30]);

console.dir(x);
```

As you suggest in your comment that you wouldn't like to use anything other than basic javascript, and no arrays, here's an implementation like that:

```js
var numberOne = 13;
var numberTwo = 30;
var numberThree = 30;
var numberFour = 30;

var totalSum = numberOne + numberTwo + numberThree + numberFour;

var evenSplit = Math.floor(totalSum / 4);

numberOne = evenSplit + (totalSum - (4 * evenSplit));
numberTwo = evenSplit;
numberThree = evenSplit;
numberFour = evenSplit;

console.log(numberOne, numberTwo, numberThree, numberFour);
```

- This code isn't very good. It'd be more difficult than it should be to change this code to, for instance, change how many numbers are being handled, or how the sum is split between the numbers
- This code is also not very good because it mutates variables. Figuring out what `numberOne` is at different parts of this code is fairly easy, but following this pattern means that further changes could make things difficult to follow.

One final point; when you ask a question on Stack Overflow, you'll get better answers if you put your requirements in your original question. Further, what exactly is 'basic' javascript? And why can't you use arrays? Including this type of thing will get you to the point faster and will prevent you from wasting people's time.

Comment: this solution is very very elegant.

Comment: Note you can change `evenly` to a function `const evenly = () => Math.floor(...)` and then use `const asList = Array.from(...).map(evenly)`. Also note `Array.from` accepts a `map` callback as its second argument - so with your current code it's just `const asList = Array.from(new Array(numbers.length).keys(), () => evenly)`.

Comment: extending on @JackBashford comment: or simply do `const asList = Array(numbers.length).fill(evenly);` and then you can do `asList[0] += remainder; return asList;` instead of creating yet another array.

Comment: @Thomas I have a preference against mutating arrays... if performance was an issue then not creating another array would be much better. Added your `.fill` though, thanks!

Comment: @JackBashford some great suggestions!

Comment: Thanks @OliverRadini, always glad to help.

Comment: I am trying to answer this code without any arrays. I am allowed to only use basic javascript and things like ```=>``` that symbol makes my code have the parenthesized pattern error. ): Thanks for the attempt tho.

Answer (score 2):

You could add all values, get the floored part and get the increment for the first number by getting the missing delta.

```js
var a = 1,
    b = 3
    c = 4
    d = 9,
    sum = a + b + c + d,
    even = Math.floor(sum / 4),
    number1 = sum - even * 3,
    number2 = even,
    number3 = even,
    number4 = even;

console.log(number1, number2, number3, number4);
```

Comment: I am trying to answer this code without any arrays. I am allowed to only use basic javascript and things like ```=>``` that symbol makes my code have the parenthesized pattern error. ): Thanks for the attempt tho.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function evenlyDistribution(num) {
  let sum = num.reduce(function(a, c) {
    a+=c;
    return a;
  }, 0);
  let len = num.length;
  const evenly = Math.floor(sum/ len);
  const res = new Array(len);
 
  while (--len > 0) {
    res[len] = evenly;
    sum -= evenly;
  }
  res[len] = sum;
  return res;
}

console.log(evenlyDistribution([13,30,30,30]))
```

Comment: I am trying to answer this code without any arrays. I am allowed to only use basic javascript and things like ```=>``` that symbol makes my code have the parenthesized pattern error. ): Thanks for the attempt tho.

Comment: @Droozie I removed the ES6 arrow function. Please have a look if it works for you